# Android media player stops at last song

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Hi how can I make the mediaplayer continue after it plays the last song in a listview?

```
 `mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
              btnNext.performClick();
           }
   });`
```

I have tried to perform a click after the song finishes and it stops at the last song.

Comment: Well if it reaches the end of the list what else do you expect it to do?

Comment: After it reaches the end I want it to start again at the beginning of the list